# How to use value return by postgresSQL function in another query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am calling PostgreSQL function that returns me the text, How can I store this value in local variable and use the value/variable in another query. ?

Comment: Just use the function in the other query directly

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what exactly you mean by a local variable - there is no such thing in SQL.  In this case, just use the function in the place where you would put your variable (like a_horse_with_no_name suggested in his comment), like

```
SELECT important_thing FROM fancy_table WHERE it_thing_happened > now();
```

`now()` is a function, and illustrates the case nicely.

If you are about PL/pgSQL variables, you can do

```
[...]
my_timestamp := now();  -- not very meaningful IRL
[...]
```

Note that you can do this only inside a PL/pgSQL function or a `DO` block.

Last, if you mean a `psql` (that is, client-side) variable, you can use the [`\gset` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-psql.html):

```
test=# SELECT now() AS ts
test-# \gset i
test=# \echo :ts
2017-05-31 10:34:48.148068+02
```

Note that `\gset` is available from `psql` version 9.3 only.